# Multiple IP's using one NIC connectivity problem - Windows

Tags: networking, windows-7, ip, gateway, nic

I have a frame relay network that is directly connected to a GPRS network. I also have a ADSL high speed network and recently I have been trying to achieve the following network configuration using windows 7 (Also tried XP) with no success to date. On one server I have two NIC's NIC1 I would like the following two static IP address's 10.0.1.110 and 10.0.1.200 the cisco router has a default gateway of 10.0.1.1 the ADSL is DHCP. NIC1 and the cisco router do not have access to the internet. NIC2 is setup for DHCP with a primary DNS and secondary DNS configured to enable internet connectivity.

With NIC1 all incoming TCP connections are from IP address's starting with 10.192.x.x I cannot establish a TCP connection to both 10.0.1.110 and 10.0.1.200. Its either one or the other. I have a static route implemented in windows of: route -p 10.192.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.0.1.1 metric 1

I have tried leaving out the gateway in the NIC1 and many other combinations with no success. Can anyone please help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I probably haven't explained the network application I am trying to achieve as clearly as I would liked. I have attached a network diagram on one of my websites that can be downloaded. www.radionetmonitoring.com/files/network.zip hopefully this explains my issue a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the ADSL and it's default gateway affects this scenario.
Try disabling it to be sure.

The problem might be that that reply comes from different IP than which was requested. This might complicate things for the cisco router or the client connecting.

The standard way is to add loopback devices to windows and put a subnet and a bunch if IPs there, and route them from the cisco via the windows ethernet IP.

TL;DR: Get rid of the 10.0.1.200 and use loopback address 10.0.2.1

Comment: I probably haven't explained the network application I am trying to achieve as clearly as I would liked. I have attached a network diagram on one of my websites that can be downloaded. www.radionetmonitoring.com/files/network.zip hopefully this explains my issue a little clearer.

Comment: Just resolved the problem. I deleted all the 0.0.0.0 persistent routes and added the following:

Route –p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.0.1.1 metric 1 if 11

Route –p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.0.1.1 metric 1 if 13

Bingo.

Thanks for your help.